# How to generate a SVG without embedded images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg

I'm using Photoshop to convert images to SVG, but I need a flexible SVG file, I don't want embedded images. My images need to stay in another path, that SVG which will refer and to include.

Can I can generate an SVG in Photoshop that will refer and include a image?

Comment: Have you looked at the help file or help option already just in case?

Comment: photoshop isn't a svg editor so its ways to work with svg are limited maybe you can do what you want with Inkscape which is a true SVG Editor

Comment: @konqui Yes, I decided to switch to Inkscape.